# checking the dropdownchecklist based on database values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dropdownchecklist

i want to check the dropdowncheck list based on database values

my script

```
  <script>
    function myfunction(para) {
        $(document).ready(function (para) {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_s10').val(para);
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_s10').dropdownchecklist('refresh');
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_s10').dropdownchecklist();
        });
    }
</script>
```

my c# page

```
 int[] para;
    para = new int[] { 1,2,3 };

    pl.qid = questionID;
    Profile.questionid.questionID = questionID;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script     type='text/javascript'>myFunction("+para+");</script>", false);
```

im tired of searching the result can some body guide me how to

check the dropdowncheck based on database values

thanks in advance

im using this dropdowncheck

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Comment: `myFunction([" + string.join(",", para) + "]);`

Comment: but why to join that string?

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting a string of Javascript to the page in RegisterStartupScript, so you need to format `para` into a correct string representation of its values. At the moment, it probably just outputs something like `myFunction(System.Array)`.

So you need a string representing a comma-separated list of the values in `para`. The [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) method will let you do this:

```
int[] para;
para = new int[] { 1,2,3 };

pl.qid = questionID;
Profile.questionid.questionID = questionID;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp",
    "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction([" + string.join(",", para) + "]);</script>", false);
```

This should correctly output `myFunction([1,2,3]);`.

As a general rule, if you aren't sure why some server-generated javascript or html is not behaving, always do a view source first to see what is actually being output and what you need to investigate.